# Selecting Candlestick data (max, min, open, close) for specific period of time

Tags: mysql, sql, charts

I'm working on candlestick chart data. I have a database table (MySql) with

```
created                  value
2017-09-25 17:55:04    3322.09
2017-09-25 18:00:03    3317.49
2017-09-25 18:05:02    3316.12
2017-09-25 18:10:03    3325.16
2017-09-25 18:15:04    3326.01
2017-09-25 18:20:03    3330.49
2017-09-25 18:25:04    3331.49
2017-09-25 18:30:04    3335.24
2017-09-25 18:35:03    3347.13
2017-09-25 18:40:03    3343.21
2017-09-25 18:45:05    3341.78
2017-09-25 18:50:03    3339.64
2017-09-25 18:55:04    3336.12
2017-09-25 19:00:04    3327.73
2017-09-25 19:05:03    3327.96
2017-09-25 19:10:04    3325.93
```

And I'm trying to select a maximum, minimum, open value, close value for any period of time (e.g. 15 minutes or every 4 hours, every 6 days etc.)

So far I have

```
SELECT p.created, HOUR(`DATE`), MAX(p.value), MIN(p.value) 
FROM price 
GROUP BY DATE(`DATE`),HOUR(`DATE`)
```

Not so complicated. It gives me maximum and minimum from every hour, so for minutes and "full" periods like  days, weeks, month I can use MONTH, DAY etc. functions.

Any idea how to build a query for any period of time, let's say 28 minutes or 31 hours etc? Also, this works for maximum and minimum, but I also need a opening value (first) for time period and close value (last).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1 for how to get the opening and closing values for time periods.

Comment: To get a specific period of time, use `WHERE created BETWEEN start_time AND end_time`

Comment: @Barmar - no, please _don't_ use `BETWEEN`.  Especially as there are timestamps with sub-second precision, it would be better to use an exclusive upper-bound (`<`), before something unintended happens.

Comment: @Jakub - I usually like to construct a temporary/virtual table (usually just an inline reference) of grouping ranges.  This is easiest with a calendar table and numbers table, but the idea is to get something like a `(groupId=1, start='2014-01-01 00:00:00.000', end=start + 28 minutes)` that you can then group on, and is usually helpful for hitting indices, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To group on arbitrary periods of time, you can take the UNIX time value of your `created` column (i.e. the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch) and divide by the size of your desired periods, taking only the integer part of the resulting quotient (and discarding the remainder).  So, to group every 28 minutes:

```
SELECT   FROM_UNIXTIME(28*60 * (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) DIV (28*60))) grp_id
         MIN(value)    min_value,
         MAX(value)    max_value,
         MIN(created)  min_created,
         MAX(created)  max_created
FROM     price
GROUP BY grp_id
```

You'll notice that I've also selected the `min_created` and `max_created`, which yield the times of the first and last values in each group.  You can then join the result back to the `price` table again to obtain the `value`s of the relevant records (this is essentially an instance of the "[groupwise maximum/minimum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)" problem):

```
SELECT t.grp_id,
       t.min_value,
       t.max_value,
       price_min.value first_value,
       price_max.value last_value
FROM (
  SELECT   FROM_UNIXTIME(28*60 * (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) DIV (28*60))) grp_id
           MIN(value)    min_value,
           MAX(value)    max_value,
           MIN(created)  min_created,
           MAX(created)  max_created
  FROM     price
  GROUP BY grp_id
) t JOIN price price_min ON price_min.created = t.min_created
    JOIN price price_max ON price_max.created = t.max_created
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30abb8/4/0).

Comment: :winces: ouch.  No index for you, come back, one year.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Depends on the size of the dataset.  By all means cache `grp_id` in an indexed column if need be.

Comment: What?  Um, no.  That would assume the groups are stable, which I tend to consider unlikely (at least two have already been mentioned).  I'd much rather solve the general problem of getting joinable, indexable criteria.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: I look forward to seeing your proposed solution.

Comment: If the table "price" contains 2 or more records with same date (created), then this SQL may return 2 or more records with same "grp_id" (because of joins).

Comment: @OsoianMarcel: which of those multiple records would you like MySQL to select (and which would you like it to filter)?  If there’s no way to differentiate, then returning the set of all such matching records to the application for it to decide how to handle seems to me to be correct behaviour.  If there is some way to differentiate, then that should be specified and added to the join criteria.